# ArchUnit: Most elegant way to check if packages depend on each other

Tags: java, archunit

I have two packages `com.myapp.foo` and `com.myapp.bar` and I want to know the most elegant way to explicitly check if those two packages (and only those, as there are some more `com.myapp.XX`) do not depend on each other.

This is what I have right now (working splendid):

```
    SliceAssignment packagesFooAndBar = new SliceAssignment() {
        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "foo and bar";
        }

        @Override
        public SliceIdentifier getIdentifierOf(JavaClass javaClass) {
            if (javaClass.getPackageName().startsWith("com.myapp.foo")) {
                return SliceIdentifier.of("foo");
            }
            if (javaClass.getPackageName().startsWith("com.myapp.bar")) {
                return SliceIdentifier.of("bar");
            }
            return SliceIdentifier.ignore();
        }
    };
    @ArchTest
    final ArchRule packagesFooAndBarNotDependOnEachOther = SlicesRuleDefinition
        .slices()
        .assignedFrom(packagesFooAndBar)
        .should()
        .notDependOnEachOther();
```

Is there a more elegant way, maybe without using the `SliceAssignment`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use two rules.

```
@ArchTest
final ArchRule fooShouldNotDependOnBar = ArchRuleDefinition
.classes()
.that().resideInAnyPackage("com.myapp.foo")
.should().onlyDependOnClassesThat()
.resideOutsideOfPackage("com.myapp.bar");

@ArchTest
final ArchRule barShouldNotDependOnFoo = ArchRuleDefinition
.classes()
.that().resideInAnyPackage("com.myapp.bar")
.should().onlyDependOnClassesThat()
.resideOutsideOfPackage("com.myapp.foo");
```

If you want to write the same in a single rule without custom classes, the following should work. I'm not sure if I would call it *elegant* though, since it's seems a bit complex. There are probably better ways to write it in a single rule.

```
@ArchTest
final ArchRule packagesFooAndBarNotDependOnEachOther = SlicesRuleDefinition
    .slices()
    .matching("com.myapp.(*)")
    .should()
    .notDependOnEachOther()
    .ignoreDependency(
        JavaClass.Predicates.resideOutsideOfPackages("com.myapp.foo", "com.myapp.bar"),
        DescribedPredicate.alwaysTrue())
    .ignoreDependency(
        DescribedPredicate.alwaysTrue(),
        JavaClass.Predicates.resideOutsideOfPackages("com.myapp.foo", "com.myapp.bar"))
    );
```

The rule first matches all direct sub-packages of `com.myapp`. The first `ignoreDependency` then excludes all dependencies from classes outside of the given packages (to allow e.g. `com.myapp.xx` to access `com.myapp.foo`). The second `ignoreDependency` excludes all dependencies from the given packages to any outside package (to allow e.g. `com.myapp.foo` to access `com.myapp.xx`).